how to leverage pgbouncer and close connections after query finished
im using drizzle to query timescale db which has pgbouncer in front of and I'm currently having a max_connection issues problem where there are too many connections in idle state.
Initially I have been setting a new connection like this:
import type { Connection } from './postgres.connection';
import type { Options } from 'postgres';

import postgres from 'postgres';

export const timescaleConnection = async <T extends Connection = Connection>(
  options?: Options<T>,
) => {
  const databaseUrl = process.env['TIMESCALE_DATABASE_URL'] ?? '';

  return postgres<T>(databaseUrl, {
    idle_timeout: 20, // 20 seconds
    ...options,
  });
};


But they don't seem to be killed automatically.
How to handle that properly using drizzle?

What kind of pooling do you use? https://www.pgbouncer.org/usage.html

@FrankHeikens Session pooling

I think you can use await sql.end() . I would also start using transaction pooling

but i would need to do that for every single query I'm doing? Also I don't use transaction most of the time, that wouldn't still be idle?

If you don't start a transaction, the "transaction" will be over when your single query is done. And the connection can be used by another process and you need less connections overall. Session pooling is hardly pooling because every process still has its own database connection that isn't shared at all.
